# Using QSignalMapper for communication between QGraphicsItems

Tags: python, pyside, qgraphicsitem, qsignalmapper

The code below shows my attempt to get several movable `VerticalLineSegment` objects (derived from `QGraphicsLineItem` and `QObject`) to signal one (using a `QSignalMapper`) another when they move. I'd appreciate help as to why the `VerticalLineSegment` slot `updateX` is not triggered.

(Going forward the goal will be to have the `VerticalLineSegment`s in different `QGraphicsScene`s but I thought it best to keep it simple for now.)

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys


class VerticalLineSegment( QtCore.QObject , QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem ):
    onXMove = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, x , y0 , y1 , parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.__init__( self , x , y0 , x , y1 , parent)

        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SizeAllCursor)

    def itemChange( self , change , value ):
        if change is QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange:
            self.onXMove.emit()
            value.setY(0)  # Restrict movements along horizontal direction
            return value
        return QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.itemChange(self, change , value )

    def shape(self):
        path = super(VerticalLineSegment, self).shape()
        stroker = QtGui.QPainterPathStroker()
        stroker.setWidth(5)
        return stroker.createStroke(path)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.shape().boundingRect()

    # slot
    def updateX(self , object ):
        print "slot"        


class CustomScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self , parent=None):
        super(CustomScene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper()

    def addItem( self , item ):
        self.signalMapper.setMapping( item , item )
        item.onXMove.connect(self.signalMapper.map )
        self.signalMapper.mapped.connect(item.updateX)
        return QtGui.QGraphicsScene.addItem(self,item)


class Editor(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Editor, self).__init__(parent)

        scene = CustomScene()

        line0 = VerticalLineSegment( 10 , 210 , 300 )
        line1 = VerticalLineSegment( 10 , 110 , 200 )
        line2 = VerticalLineSegment( 10 ,  10 , 100 )

        scene.addItem( line0 )
        scene.addItem( line1 )
        scene.addItem( line2 )

        view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        view.setScene( scene )

        self.setGeometry( 250 , 250 , 600 , 600 )
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        self.show()


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Editor()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PySide (and also in PySide2, PyQt4 and PyQt5) it is not possible to inherit from QGraphicsItem and QObject (only double inheritance is allowed in special cases)

So a possible solution is to use the composition, that is, to have a QObject as an attribute and that this has the signal:

```py
import sys
import uuid
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class Signaller(QtCore.QObject):
    onXMove = QtCore.Signal()


class VerticalLineSegment(QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem):
    def __init__(self, _id, x, y0, y1, parent=None):
        super(VerticalLineSegment, self).__init__(x, y0, x, y1, parent)
        self._id = _id
        self.signaller = Signaller()
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SizeAllCursor)

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change is QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange:
            self.signaller.onXMove.emit()
            value.setY(0)  # Restrict movements along horizontal direction
            return value
        return QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.itemChange(self, change, value)

    def shape(self):
        path = super(VerticalLineSegment, self).shape()
        stroker = QtGui.QPainterPathStroker()
        stroker.setWidth(5)
        return stroker.createStroke(path)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.shape().boundingRect()

    def updateX(self, _id):
        print("slot", _id)


class CustomScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomScene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)

    def addItem(self, item):
        if hasattr(item, "_id"):
            item.signaller.onXMove.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(item.signaller, item._id)
            self.signalMapper.mapped[str].connect(item.updateX)
        super(CustomScene, self).addItem(item)


class Editor(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Editor, self).__init__(parent)

        scene = CustomScene()

        line0 = VerticalLineSegment(str(uuid.uuid4()), 10.0, 210.0, 300.0)
        line1 = VerticalLineSegment(str(uuid.uuid4()), 10.0, 110.0, 200.0)
        line2 = VerticalLineSegment(str(uuid.uuid4()), 10.0, 10.0, 100.0)

        scene.addItem(line0)
        scene.addItem(line1)
        scene.addItem(line2)

        view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        view.setScene(scene)

        self.setGeometry(250, 250, 600, 600)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        self.show()
```

Or use QGraphicsObject:

```py
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class VerticalLineSegment(QtGui.QGraphicsObject):
    onXMove = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self, x, y0, y1, parent=None):
        super(VerticalLineSegment, self).__init__(parent)
        self._line = QtCore.QLineF(x, y0, x, y1)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SizeAllCursor)

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        painter.drawLine(self._line)

    def shape(self):
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(self._line.p1())
        path.lineTo(self._line.p2())
        stroker = QtGui.QPainterPathStroker()
        stroker.setWidth(5)
        return stroker.createStroke(path)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.shape().boundingRect()

    def itemChange(self, change, value):
        if change is QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange:
            self.onXMove.emit()
            value.setY(0)  # Restrict movements along horizontal direction
            return value
        return QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.itemChange(self, change, value)

    def updateX(self , obj):
        print("slot", obj) 

class CustomScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomScene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.signalMapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper(self)

    def addItem(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, QtCore.QObject):
            item.onXMove.connect(self.signalMapper.map)
            self.signalMapper.setMapping(item, item)
            self.signalMapper.mapped[QtCore.QObject].connect(item.updateX)
        super(CustomScene, self).addItem(item)


class Editor(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Editor, self).__init__(parent)

        scene = CustomScene()

        line0 = VerticalLineSegment(10.0, 210.0, 300.0)
        line1 = VerticalLineSegment(10.0, 110.0, 200.0)
        line2 = VerticalLineSegment(10.0, 10.0, 100.0)

        scene.addItem(line0)
        scene.addItem(line1)
        scene.addItem(line2)

        view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        view.setScene(scene)

        self.setGeometry(250, 250, 600, 600)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        self.show()
```

Comment: @eyllansec The line `self.signalMapper.mapped[str].connect(print)` in the first version generates the error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: @Olumide What version of python and pyside do you use?

Comment: @eyllansec My Python version is 2.7.15rc1, PySide 1.2.2, QtCore version 4.8.7. BTW, I came  up with a somewhat similar solution. I'll post it in a moment. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: @Olumide I modified the first code to be compatible with python2 and python3. The problem is that in python2 print is not a callable, on the other hand in python3 it is. Try with my new code

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because, although my answer is simpler because it avoids the use of QSignalMapper, this answer addresses the question that I asked i.e. how to use a QSignalMapper to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I came up with. Like @eyllanesc's first solution it uses a signaller which I call a Broadcaster instead of `QSignalMapper` which is now [obsolete](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html)/[deprecated](https://github.com/ubports/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/issues/11). Here are the relevant changes:

```
class VerticalLineSegment( QtCore.QObject , QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem ):
    onXMove = QtCore.Signal( int , int )

    def __init__(self, x , y0 , y1 , parent=None):
        ...
        self.index = -1
        ...

    def updateX( self , id , x ):
        if id is not self.index:
            # Disconnect and reconnect to avoid a signal cycle
            self.onXMove.disconnect()
            self.setX( x )
            self.onXMove.connect( self.sender().onXMove )


# Alternative to signal mapper
class Broadcaster( QtCore.QObject ):
    onXMove = QtCore.Signal( int , int )    


class CustomScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self , parent=None):
        super(CustomScene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.broadcaster = Broadcaster()
        self.count = 0

    def addItem( self , item ):
        item.index = self.count
        self.count = self.count + 1
        item.onXMove.connect( self.broadcaster.onXMove )
        self.broadcaster.onXMove.connect( item.updateX )
        return QtGui.QGraphicsScene.addItem(self,item)
```

And here is the complete program

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

class VerticalLineSegment( QtCore.QObject , QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem ):
    onXMove = QtCore.Signal( int , int )

    def __init__(self, x , y0 , y1 , parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
        QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.__init__( self , x , y0 , x , y1 , parent)
        self.index = -1

        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.ItemSendsGeometryChanges)
        self.setCursor(QtCore.Qt.SizeAllCursor)

    def itemChange( self , change , value ):
        if change is QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemPositionChange:
            self.onXMove.emit( self.index , value.x() )
            value.setY(0)  # Restrict movements along horizontal direction
            return value
        return QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem.itemChange(self, change , value )

    def shape(self):
        path = super(VerticalLineSegment, self).shape()
        stroker = QtGui.QPainterPathStroker()
        stroker.setWidth(5)
        return stroker.createStroke(path)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return self.shape().boundingRect()

    def updateX( self , id , x ):
        if id is not self.index:
            self.onXMove.disconnect()
            self.setX( x )
            self.onXMove.connect( self.sender().onXMove )


class Broadcaster( QtCore.QObject ):
    onXMove = QtCore.Signal( int , int )


class CustomScene(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self , parent=None):
        super(CustomScene, self).__init__(parent)
        self.broadcaster = Broadcaster()
        self.count = 0

    def addItem( self , item ):
        item.index = self.count
        self.count = self.count + 1
        item.onXMove.connect( self.broadcaster.onXMove )
        self.broadcaster.onXMove.connect( item.updateX )
        return QtGui.QGraphicsScene.addItem(self,item)


class Editor(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Editor, self).__init__(parent)

        scene = CustomScene()

        line0 = VerticalLineSegment( 10 , 210 , 300 )
        line1 = VerticalLineSegment( 10 , 110 , 200 )
        line2 = VerticalLineSegment( 10 ,  10 , 100 )

        scene.addItem( line0 )
        scene.addItem( line1 )
        scene.addItem( line2 )

        view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
        view.setScene( scene )

        self.setGeometry( 250 , 250 , 600 , 600 )
        self.setCentralWidget(view)
        self.show()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Editor()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your explanation has an error, in Qt5  >= 5.10 it is deprecated, but you are using PySide which is based on Qt4 so for that class it is not deprecated.

Comment: Ah, true. ... But its future proof ;-)

Comment: So far I have not had to analyze the time because it is deprecated, although for these cases I do not use QSignalMapper but a model that allows you to handle the simplest things. :-)

Comment: I used to think signal mapper was "cool" but I now think its limiting because of the narrow range of data types it can re-emit. (BTW, I am trying to get your versions to update the positions of all line segments like my answer so that I can objectively compare them.)

Comment: I will add a solution using models but later, maybe it will help you. What you think you want to do is have the items of several QGraphicsScene synchronized. But I have a question, why do you have several QGraphicsScene? a QGraphicsScene can belong to several QGraphicsView

Comment: I'll gladly explain but should we do this in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/191620/using-qsignalmapper-in-to-signal-between-qgraphicsscene-objects-in-pyside?tab=general) so as not to create noise here?

Comment: @eyllanesc Can you take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768301/using-qt-model-view-framework-to-notify-qgraphicsitem-in-a-view-of-user-edit-mad) about models? Thanks