# Using Qt model/view framework to notify QGraphicsItem in a view of user-edit made in another view

Tags: pyside, qgraphicsitem, model-view

I am trying to design a multiview application to use Qt's model/view framework so that I can move lots of complex logic out of my `QGraphicsItem` classes.

As shown in the figure below, the application consists of two (or more) views each containing of an identical series of red vertical guide lines `A1` , `B1`, `C1` ... at the same horizontal positions along each view.

[image]

I'd like to ensure that when the user drags a guide line one view, say from a point `A1` to `A_1'` as shown in the figure above, all corresponding guide lines in the other views move by the same distance and in the same direction, for example from `A2` to `A2'`. Also it should not be possible to drag one guide line past another i.e. guide lines must retain their relative orders. This is part of the logic that I would like to move out of my GuideLine class, into the model.

I know dragging guide lines triggers QGraphicsItem::itemChange, as shown in the snippet below. What I don't know is how best to

1. Forward the candidate value to the model for validation (and storage). I am aware that the view is the interface "standard interface for interoperating with models through the signals and slots mechanism". The big problem, as I see it, is that `QGraphicsItem::itemChange` must immediately return validated value it cannot rely on the asynchronous signal-slot mechanism.
2. Notify the guide lines in the other views of the change without triggering creating a cascade of notifications, for example where `A1` and `B1` endlessly notify each other.

-

```
class GuideLine( QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem ):
    ...
    # Called when item is about to change to value
    def itemChange( self , change , value ):
        # TODO 
        #  1. validate value in model
        #  2. if change is valid notify peers in other views
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView could be seen as a model/view implementation where the scene would be the model and the QGraphicsView would be the view.

Two QGraphicsView can share the same scene and when you modify the scene from one view, the second one will be also updated.

A quick example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication([])
    scene = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 1000, 1000)
    view1 = QGraphicsView()
    view2 = QGraphicsView()

    item = QGraphicsRectItem(QRectF(0, 0, 40, 40))
    item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    scene.addItem(item)

    view1.setScene(scene)
    view2.setScene(scene)

    w = QWidget()
    layout = QVBoxLayout(w)
    layout.addWidget(view1)
    layout.addWidget(view2)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The rect item is movable and will move in the two views at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately sharing a scene might not work because the views need to be stretchable vertically to different heights. Also each view also has other QGraphicsItems apart from the guide lines, so multiple scenes may be required.

Comment: The `QGraphicsView` can handle their height independently of the scene and you can *hide* some item regarding to the view. So, I still think that you should use only one scene. But, if you want to use two scenes, the easiest way to achieve that would be use a custom `QGraphicsItem` and a custom model which wuold handle their positions and geometries, instead of trying to connect them to each other.

Comment: As I said, the guide lines update the other QGraphicsItems in view. In fact, in general, dragging a `QGraphicsItem`s affect a subset of the remaining items. (I didn't mention this because I wanted to keep the question simple. I thought the answer updating guide lines would be applicable to others graphics items.) That said, wouldn't this approach lead to having a ton of logic in the `QGraphicsItem`s class?