# Constraining members of group of QGraphicsItems to share each others movements in one direction

Tags: python, qgraphicsitem, pyside2

I am trying to use the `QGraphicsItemGroup` class to constrain a group of objects to move by the same amount in one (e.g. the vertical) direction as shown in the diagram below, where the vertical movement of the item B (shown by a red arrow) is shared by items A, C and D, but not its horizontal movement (which is shown by the blue arrows). See also the code below:

[image]

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore     import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui      import QBrush
from PySide2.QtWidgets  import QApplication , QGraphicsScene , QGraphicsView , QGraphicsItem , QGraphicsItemGroup , QGraphicsEllipseItem

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    graphicsView = QGraphicsView()
    graphicsView.setSceneRect( -50 , -50 , 300 , 100 )
    scene = QGraphicsScene(graphicsView)
    graphicsView.setScene(scene)

    graphicsItemGrp = QGraphicsItemGroup()
    graphicsItemGrp.setFlag( QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable )
    graphicsItemGrp.setHandlesChildEvents( False )

    brush = QBrush( Qt.black )

    item1 = QGraphicsEllipseItem( 0 , 0 , 20 , 20 )
    item1.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    item1.setCursor( Qt.SizeAllCursor )
    item1.setBrush( brush )

    item2 = QGraphicsEllipseItem( 50 , 0 , 20 , 20 )
    item2.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    item2.setCursor( Qt.SizeAllCursor )
    item2.setBrush( brush )

    item3 = QGraphicsEllipseItem( 100 , 0 , 20 , 20 )
    item3.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    item3.setCursor( Qt.SizeAllCursor )
    item3.setBrush( brush )

    item4 = QGraphicsEllipseItem( 150 , 0 , 20 , 20 )
    item4.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    item4.setCursor( Qt.SizeAllCursor )
    item4.setBrush( brush )


    graphicsItemGrp.addToGroup( item1 )
    graphicsItemGrp.addToGroup( item2 )
    graphicsItemGrp.addToGroup( item3 )
    graphicsItemGrp.addToGroup( item4 )
    scene.addItem( graphicsItemGrp )

    graphicsView.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am not certain that `QGraphicsItemGroup` is the way to go but its the most promising approach that I've been able to find.

> A QGraphicsItemGroup is a special type of compound item that treats itself and all its children as one item (i.e., all events and geometries for all children are merged together). **It's common to use item groups in presentation tools, when the user wants to group several smaller items into one big item in order to simplify moving and copying of items**.

Source Qt 5.13 [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitemgroup.html#details)

Comment: In my case with PySide2 5.13.1 on Linux with your current code it works correctly

Comment: I've just upgraded PySide2 to version 2.13.1 (from 2.12.?) and I don't see any difference. Offsets to one for are not shared by other dots. As I said I want the dots to share offsets in the Y direction but not the X direction, and there is nothing in the code that ensures this.

Comment: With your current code in my tests I see that it is shared in all directions. I think I misunderstood your question, do you want them to share only the vertical movement and not in the horizontal direction?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes.

Comment: @eyllanesc I have a solution. It relies on `QGraphicsItem.itemChange` and breaks the Qt's recommendation not to call `setPos` in `QGraphicsItem.itemChange` (or appears to) but it solves this problem as well as a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56768301/using-qt-model-view-framework-to-notify-qgraphicsitem-in-a-view-of-user-edit-mad) that I posed 2 months ago (still unanswered).

Comment: I'm reluctant to post my solution because I don't want to give bad advise.